# panic: Error 1054: Unknown column 'helloman' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, golang

Подключаюсь к БД и пытаюсь внести значения в таблицу `bot_api` значения `1337, helloman, David`.
Код:

```
package main 

import "fmt"
import "database/sql"
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"


// Global sql.DB to access the database by all handlers
var db *sql.DB 
var err error


func main() {

    Hello()

}

func Hello() {
    // Create an sql.DB and check for errors
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root@/formm")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())    
    } else {

    }
    // sql.DB should be long lived "defer" closes it once this function ends
    defer db.Close()

    // Test the connection to the database
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    rows, err := db.Prepare("insert into bot_api values ('1337', `helloman`, 'David')")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Println(rows)

}
```

Выдает ошибку: `panic: Error 1054: Unknown column 'helloman' in 'field list'`.
Значение: первое значение - `int`, второй значение - `text`, третье значение - `varchar(255)`.

Что не так я делаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо используйте `db.Exec()` вместо `db.Prepare()`:

```
res, err := db.Exec("insert into bot_api values ('1337', `helloman`, 'David')")
```

либо используйте подстановочные символы в запросе и подстановку параметров при выполнении запроса:

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("insert into bot_api values (?, ?, ?)")
...
rows, err := stmt.Exec("1337", "helloman", "David")
```

Answer (score 0):

Выдает ошибку: Unknown column 'helloman' in 'field list'
потому что в запросе "insert into bot_api values ('1337', `helloman`, 'David')" параметр helloman находится между апострофами. 
Нужно использовать одинарные кавычки, тогда ошибки не будет.